# jQuery Sortable - Keep empty space on item remove from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make a board where users can move sticky notes here and there which contain data.

I am utilizing the sortable jQuery library at the moment. It is working as it is designed to, but I want to modify the functionality a little. When I remove an item from the list, I want an empty space to be left in its place. For example, if I am removing the first item from the list, the rest of the items shouldn't be moved up and take the empty space.

Similarly, when I have only one item in a list and I remove it, I cannot add anything back to that list since the list goes away. I want to stop that from happening as well.

Here's the snippet (click to open).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.sort-me-alpha').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sort-me-gamma',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('special')) {
      ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});

$('.sort-me-beta').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sort-me-gamma',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    if (!$(ui.item).hasClass('special')) {
      ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});

$('.sort-me-gamma').sortable({
  appendTo: document.body,
  items: '.sticky',
  placeholder: "testclass",
  connectWith: '.sort-me-alpha, .sort-me-beta',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    //console.log(event, ui.item);
    //ui.item.remove(); // remove original item
  }
});

});
```

```css
  .sort-me {
    /* background-color: #3498db; */
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .sort-me-alpha {
    /* background-color: #3498db; */
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .sort-me-gamma {
    /* background-color: #3498db; */
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .sort-me-beta {
    /* background-color: #3498db; */
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: fixed;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .testclass {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .sticky {
    /* position: absolute; */
    right: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    /* transform: rotate(5deg); */
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", "Chalkboard SE", "Comic Neue", cursive; */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 51, 0.8);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  .sticky:before,
  .sticky:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .sticky:before {
    border-top: solid 8px #fff;
    border-right: solid 8px #fff;
    border-left: solid 8px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 8px transparent;
  }

  .sticky:after {
    border-bottom: solid 8px #dddd33;
    border-left: solid 8px #dddd33;
    border-right: solid 8px transparent;
    border-top: solid 8px transparent;
  }

  .ui-helper {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="sort-me-alpha">
    <div class="sticky">
      <b>Card 1</b> Put any text in here.
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <b>Card 2</b> Put any text in here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-me-beta">
    <div class="sticky">
      <b>Card n</b> Put any text in here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-me-gamma">
    <div class="sticky">
      <b>Card 3</b> Put any text in here.
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <b>Card 4</b> Put any text in here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I move *Card N* to any other list, I cannot bring it back since the list ceases to exist.

Also if I were to move *Card 3* to any other list, *Card 4* comes up and takes its place, I know this is the default behavior, but can I override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One question** per question, please. I'll answer the first one.

You should use:

```
$("#sticky-id").css('visibility','hidden');
```

The property `visibility:hidden` keeps the space as it is.

To remove an element, just use `remove()` instead of touching visibility.

If you want to add an element inside the list use:

```
remove: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log('removed'); 
    $('.sort-me-gamma').prepend('<div class="sticky">' + '<b> I am a dummy card </b>' + '</div>' );
}
```

And if you want a generic function to do this, you'll need:

```
.insertAfter('#list :nth-child(<give childnumber here>)')
```

And to get childnumber use an on click event and set an attribute which contains the ID in each card when creating HTML code, for example `id=card-number-[putherevalue]`

Comment: Well, this made no such difference since the card is going away from that list. What it does do is that it makes the card invisible in the new list it goes to. 

If you look at the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adnanchang/mdeo8me0/), I wanna move, for example, Card 3 to the first column. Once that is done, Card 4 comes up and becomes the first element of the list. I want to avoid that, I want Card 4 to stay there. 

So I was thinking I make a dummy element that just takes

Comment: With this change space should be left and you can show the card again (deleting the property visibility), that's what I understood.

Comment: So you see in the third column, there are two cards: Card 3 and Card 4. If I move Card 3 to the first column, doesn't matter which position, Card 4 in the third column comes up and becomes the _first_ card of the column. I want it to stay as the _second_ card even when Card 3 leaves the list.

Comment: Ok in that case as you mention you should create a _shadow card_ for every card which will remain in the last position and avoid other cards to get that space

Comment: Alright will work on that, will it be possible to have this shadow card be replaced? Since it is supposed to be an empty space, so if I am bringing a card on this shadow card, it should be overridden. I guess this would be a different discussion and should go in a different question. Will update on the shadow card though

Comment: To replace the card you'll need to use `remove()` instead of touching visibility. Will wait for that new question ;)

Comment: Okay, I am stuck. I can now append a new card but it is being added at the end, of course. Is there any way to check the current index of the dragged item and add the new item to that very index? Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adnanchang/mdeo8me0/)

When you move Card 3 to the first column, a dummy card comes up.

Comment: Try with this code: `remove: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log('removed');
    $('.sort-me-gamma').prepend('<div class="sticky">' +
      '<b> I am a dummy card </b>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }` instead of `append`. I've tried and it works like a charm.

Comment: Alright, that does work, but what if there are three cards, and I wanna move the middle one, now when I add a dummy element, do I prepend or append?

Comment: In that case you should implement a generic function getting child number and then using `.insertAfter('#list :nth-child(<give childnumber here>)')`

Comment: How do I get that child number? Through event? ui? ui.item?

Comment: Get `this` on click event and set an attribute which contains the ID in each card when creating HTML code, for example `id=card-number-[putherevalue]`

Comment: Hey, I got it!

I get the index of the card moving in the start event and put it in a variable. I use the variable in the remove event incase the card leaves the list and I make a dummy card at the nth child like you suggested. Should I post it as an answer or you do it? I am not familiar of the rules here

Here's the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adnanchang/mdeo8me0/15/)

Comment: Okay, may be you can edit your actual post so people don't have to read through all these comments and I'll mark your answer as correct!

Comment: I've just added all responses, hope it fits for next users :)